# How to replace/remove a character in a character buffer?

Tags: c++

I am trying to modify someone's code which uses this line:

```
out.write(&vecBuffer[0], x.length());
```

However, I want to modify the buffer beforehand so it removes any bad characters I don't want to be output. For example if the buffer is "Test%string" and I want to get rid of %, I want to change the buffer to "Test string" or "Teststring" whichever is easier.

Comment: I've tried the replace() function but that seems to only work on strings and not buffers

Comment: What is your character buffer `char[]` or `vector<char>` ?

Comment: std::vector<char> vecBuffer; (sorry if this was important and I needed to mention earlier, I'm still learning)

Comment: @user1947180 `std::replace` works on anything which has an iterator, or can be accessed via pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::replace` will allow replacing one specific character with
another, e.g. `'%'` with `' '`.  Just call it normally:

```
std::replace( vecBuffer.begin(), vecBuffer.end(), '%', ' ' );
```

Replace the `'%'` with a predicate object, call `replace_if`,
and you can replace any character for which the predicate
object returns `true`.  But always with the same character.  For
more flexibility, there's `std::transform`, which you pass
a function which takes a `char`, and returns a `char`; it will
be called on each character in the buffer.

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
vecBuffer.erase(
    std::remove( vecBuffer.begin(), vecBuffer.end(), '%' ).
    vecBuffer.end() );
```

To remove the characters.  Here too, you can replace `remove`
with `remove_if`, and use a predicate, which may match many
different characters.

Comment: What is replace_if vs. replace? Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: +1 for only erase/remove idiom here - which would be the standard way to do it

Comment: @user1947180 They're two different functions in the standard library; replace takes a value, and replaces anything which matches that value, and replace_if takes a predicate---something that can be called with a value, and returns true or false.  There are several function pairs like this: find and find_if, remove and remove_if, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest library you can use is probably the [Boost String Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) library.

```
boost::replace_all(buffer, "%", "");
```

will replace all occurrences of `%` by nothing, in place. You could specify `" "` as a replacement, or even `"REPLACEMENT"`, as suits you.

Comment: I tried

boost::replace_all(&vecBuffer[0], " ", ""); 

But this returned a massive slew of errors. I included #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

Comment: You may want to mention how to deal with the `x.length()` in the call to `out.write`, because the ending bytes of the post-replacement buffer may contain data that is no longer valid.

Comment: I would modify the buffer first before acquiring the length

Comment: @user1947180 The problem is, you may not be able to "acquire the length" once the buffer is modified, because only the code that performs the modification has enough information of the new length.

Comment: @user1947180: It is quite obvious it will not work, the algorithm requires a *container*, not a bare pointer. Just use the container: `boost::replace_all(vecBuffer, " ", "");`, see demo on [liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1XHKCH$1).

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string str("Test string");
std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), boost::is_any_of(" "), '');
std::cout << str << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the boost library. The easiest way is to replace the `%` character with a space, using std::replace() from the `<algorithm>` header:

```
std::replace(vecBuffer.begin(), vecBuffer.end(), '%', ' ');
```

I assume that `vecBuffer`, as its name implies, is an std::vector. If it's actually a plain array (or pointer), then you would do:

```
std::replace(vecBuffer, vecBuffer + SIZE_OF_BUFFER, '%', ' ');
```

SIZE_OF_BUFFER should be the size of the array (or the amount of characters in the array you want to process, if you don't want to convert the whole buffer.)

Comment: Actually, whether `vecBuffer` is a vector or not should not matter, as long as it provides Forward Iteration and mutable content.

Comment: `.begin()` will not work on a plain array. That's the reason I provided the two versions :)

Comment: Well, there was only one version when I checked ;) In C++11, the favored style would be to use free-standing `begin(vecBuffer)` (and `end(vecBuffer)`), there are overloads for array types and they *do the right thing* (tm).

Comment: If `vecBuffer` is a C style array, it's `std::replace( begin( vecBuffer ), end( vecBuffer ), '%', ' ' );`.  With an `std::` before `begin` and `end` in C++11, and the namespace you've put your utility programs in otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a function

```
bool goodChar( char c );
```

That returns `true` for characters you are approved of and `false` otherwise,
then how about

```
void fixBuf( char* buf, unsigned int len ) {
    unsigned int co = 0;
    for ( unsigned int cb = 0 ; cb < len ; cb++ ) {
        if goodChar( buf[cb] ) {
           buf[co] = buf[cb];
           co++;
        }
    }
}
```